# How do I add mods to Minecraft on Xbox360?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console, minecraft-mods

I play Minecraft on my Xbox360. I want to add mods on my Xbox360 but *how do I do that*? I would like to play the Pixelmon mod on my Xbox360 because I like Pokemon, but I don't know how.

Comment: Hello, I cleaned it up for you this time, but in the future please mind the spelling, and avoid typing in all caps. Also leave out the hashtags, they do nothing here. While we do not necessarily expect everyone to post in *perfect* English, we do request that some effort is made to write to the best of your ability in order to maintain a high standard of quality on our site. Please (re)read though the [tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and check out our [help pages](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2):

Modding in the console community is a rare instance. To allow modifications to your current game, you would require a JTagged console. Keep in mind that having a tampered console is against the Terms and Conditions enforced by minecraft, and you face the risk of receiving a console ban.

If you are interested in the use of modifications in microsoft, you may want to invest in a version of minecraft for the PC, as it fully supports mods. There is far less hassle, and you won't be banned.

Also, with that said. There are very select few modifications opened to the Xbox Minecraft community, as modifying the game is far more complicated than it would be on the PC platform.

Comment: Additionally, mods are typically built to run on specific versions of Minecraft - running a mod designed for version **1.7.x** on older (1.6.x) or newer (1.8.x) versions of Minecraft will often result in errors, crashes, and unintended behavior. As the Pixelmon mod is being developed for PC, it is unlikely that they have a version that is compatible with console-specific Minecraft builds (even if it were possible to mod the console version at all).

Comment: "Unlikely" the only thing the games have in common is the theme and the name. One is written in java (which is quite friendly to being modded) and the other in C++ (which is uhm, not friendly to being modded except in ways the programmers build in explicitly)